# How to sort the object array in mongodb using node js which is dynamically created?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting

so my database looks like this is mongodb

```
{
  {
    _id:'some hash value'
    'guildId':'id of the guild'
    'level':{
      'stats':{
        '2231553224':{
           'totalxp':230
        },
       '462462642':{
           'totalxp':30
        },
        '1563463224':{
           'totalxp':117
        },
        '5763453224':{
           'totalxp':53
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the level.stats is a collection of objects which are dynamically formed.
i want to sort the level.stats field with the `totalxp` field which is present inside each object in the field.
i am unable to sort it using
`const dat = await levelCollection.findOne({'guildId':message.guild.id},{projection:{"level.stats":1},sort:[['totalxp','desc']]})` 
please help. thank you

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO ! Are you using `mongoose` ?

Comment: No I am using the official mongo client

Comment: are you trying to update the field `level` then sort them after?

Comment: no i am not updating anything.. just sorting them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to sort nested documents with varying field names is using [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/index.html) query.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { guildId: message.guild.id } },
  { $addFields: { level_stats: { $objectToArray: "$level.stats" } } }, 
  { $unwind: "$level_stats" },
  { $sort: { "level_stats.v.totalxp": 1 } },
  { $group: { _id: "$_id", level_stats: { $push: "$level_stats" }, doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" } } },
  { $project: { "level.stats": { $arrayToObject: "$level_stats" }, guildId: "$doc.guildId" } }, 
])
```

**The Output [edit add]:**

```
{
        "_id" : "some hash value",
        "guildId" : "id of the guild",
        "level" : {
                "stats" : {
                        "462462642" : {
                                "totalxp" : 30
                        },
                        "5763453224" : {
                                "totalxp" : 53
                        },
                        "1563463224" : {
                                "totalxp" : 117
                        },
                        "2231553224" : {
                                "totalxp" : 230
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: prasad_ I see that some places you wrote level_stats and in some places it's level.stats.. just to be clear I have level.stats in the database.. so I think you have renamed level.stats to level_stats... I will try and let you know.. thanks a lot... Also I can do `const res = db.collection.aggregate()` right?

Comment: The output will be as you had expected - I had included the output in the answer. The query syntax: [Using aggregate queries with NodeJS driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/tutorials/aggregation/).

Comment: i am soo sorry i didnt see the output... i am testing it right away

Comment: prasad_ i have a question. so like you see i did the `.findOne({'guildId':message.guild.id})` so i need to only sort the respective guildId how do i do that in aggregate cause i think it sorts the entire database... `message.guild.id` would be unique for different guilds

Comment: I will edit the code to add a condition using the `$match` stage at the beginning of the pipeline. Match stage allows filter documents based upon a condition (just like in the `find` method).

Comment: Yes yes I did some digging and found it.... Thanks a lot